# Make last name field unique for guests on WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to make the entered values in last name field in checkout page unique or validate for duplicates.

This is for guests users only where they fill the first name and last name. I currently have this snippet but this does not have the desired result. Any advice?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', 'lastname_field' );

function validate_lastname_field($exist_error )  {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $billing_last_name = $_POST['billing_last_name'];
    $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `abc_usermeta` where meta_key = "billing_last_name" AND meta_value = "'.$billing_last_name.'"');
    if ( $results ) {
        $exist_error->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( 'Last name already exists.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    return $exist_error;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the last name to be unique?  That means if my last name is 'Foo' and your last name is 'Foo', and I checkout before you, you won't be able to.  I don't understand the logic here?

Comment: Would be a problem in germany because we have a lot of `Meier` for example. But in case this is what you want - you are using the wrong hook for validation, mate. You need to use `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes

- Use `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` action hook for validation
- Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, use prepared statements
- $wpdb: prefix is giving the table prefix of the site. So generating table name dynamically through this will help to keep the query correct even on many sites with different table prefixes
- Your code will be executed for both guests and logged in users

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation( $data, $error ) {
    // Only for guests
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    global $wpdb;

    // Billing last name
    $billing_last_name = $data['billing_last_name'];
    
    // Executes a SQL query and returns the entire SQL result.
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'billing_last_name' AND meta_value = %s", $billing_last_name ) );

    // NOT empty
    if ( $results ) {
        $error->add( 'validation', __( 'Last name already exists.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 10, 2 );
```